# Usage of TPL vs Parallel.ForEach() on file processing

Tags: c#, comparative-review, file, task-parallel-library, .net-core

i've been working on an implementation of a my own from scratch set of library [Astron](https://github.com/thenameless314159/Astron) and I wanted to get my TPL usage reviewed because i'm not confident with this technology :/

My app is currently unpacking .d2p files, which is a custom file format from a french game called Dofus, it's simply an archive of others inflated archives of another custom file format .dlm. Here is the current output of my app :

[image: application output]
The progress bars came [from here](https://github.com/goblinfactory/konsole).

So everything seems to works as expected, files are processes concurrently, 308mo of .dlm files are parsed deflated in 10sec, that is exactly what i wants it to do but i may have misused the TPL. The full project can be [found at this address](https://github.com/thenameless314159/Astron.Unpacker), but the portion of code I want to get reviewed is from `src/Astron.Unpacker/Managers/D2PManager.cs` :

```
public class D2PManager : BaseFileManager
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly string _dlmFilesFolder;
    public D2PManager(IContainer container) : base(container)
    {
        _logger = ServiceLocator.Logger;
        _dlmFilesFolder = container.GetInstance<Settings>().DlmOutputFolder;
    }

    public async Task UnpackAll(string[] filesPath)
    {
        _logger.Log<D2PManager>(LogLevel.Info, $"Attempting to unpack {filesPath.Length} d2p files...");

        var tasks = new List<Task>(filesPath.Length);
        tasks.AddRange(filesPath.Select(d2PFilePath => UnpackD2PFile(d2PFilePath)));

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task UnpackD2PFile(string path)
    {
        var d2PFile      = new FileAccessor(path);
        var metaUnpacker = new D2PFileMetadataUnpacker(_binaryFactory, _serDes);
        metaUnpacker.Unpack(d2PFile);

        var archiveUnpacker = new DlmArchivesUnpacker(_binaryFactory, _serDes, metaUnpacker.Value);
        archiveUnpacker.Unpack(d2PFile);

        var progressCount = 1;
        var progressBar   = new ProgressBar(PbStyle.SingleLine, archiveUnpacker.Values.Count);
        progressBar.Refresh(0, Path.GetFileName(d2PFile.FullPath));
        await Task.Delay(10); // doesn't print all either way
        foreach (var archive in archiveUnpacker.Values)
        {
            var filePath      = (_dlmFilesFolder + archive.RelativePath).Replace('/', '\\');
            var fileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
            using var decompressedData = new MemoryStream();
            using var deflatedStream = new DeflateStream(new MemoryStream(archive.CompressedData), 
                CompressionMode.Decompress);

            await deflatedStream.CopyToAsync(decompressedData);
            if (!Directory.Exists(fileDirectory)) Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDirectory);

            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, decompressedData.GetBuffer());
            progressBar.Refresh(progressCount, filePath);
            progressCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my questions :

- If I don't add the `Task.Delay()` right after the processbar initialization, the files seems to be processed synchronously (the progress bar show up when the last completed), why does it happen ?
- Is it right to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on `Task.WhenAll()` ?
- Am I starting every tasks the right way ? Shouldn't I use `Task.Run()` instead with `Task.WaitAll()` ?

Comment: At first glance, I would say remove the ConfigureAwait(false) and await Task.Delay(10) and see what happens...

Comment: I would replace your current `Task.WhenAll` with `Parallel.ForEach(filesPath, ...)` and let the framework create and handle the concurrency or alternatively `filesPath.AsParallel()...` btw, you are not disposing any streams.

Comment: @dfhwze without the task.delay files are processed synchronously according to this output: https://i.imgur.com/24O9ZzX.gif as I said on the question, why should I remove the configure await ?

Comment: @t3chb0t yeah i was doing this before but Parallel foreach doesn't ensure that everything will be processed concurrently, thank you for the not disposed streams, i didn't noticed that, thanks to C#8 i just have to add using before the var definition :)

Comment: `async Task` requires an `await`, if there is nothing else you can `await` then I think you should `return Task.CompltetedTask.` and use `Task.Factory.StartNew (() => )` to call this method... but I looked through your repository and you could add some awaitable methods to make it _naturally_ awaitable but this would require changing a lot of other APIs.

Comment: Hum, i've modified my code with the Parallel.Foreach(), because before i wasn't using the progress bar to show the progression and it provide me this output : https://i.imgur.com/aWvISMv.gif with parsing in under 8 sec, which is better but the behavior is different, each tasks doesn't start at the same moment, but this is not really a problem

Comment: @NamelessK1NG replace the AddRange with tasks.AddRange(filesPath.Select(async d2PFilePath => await Task.Run(() => UnpackD2PFile(d2PFilePath)))); and remove the Delay. It should work now.

Comment: @dfhwze That way it have the same behavior as the Parallel.ForEach() and provide the same output !
Thank you very much both of you now I undestand a little bit more how the TPL shoud be used and when. I'll use the parallel foreach to keep a synchronous API

Comment: @NamelessK1NG just out of curiousity, which one is the faster; the Task or Parallel approach?

Comment: They do it both in 8 seconds with the different approach but everything is implemented using my own from scratch library Astron so it may be better with something that have been benched and optimized ^^

Comment: @NamelessK1NG Perhaps you could answer your own question for future readers to get a nice overview. I have noticed several posts about Task vs Parallel. This is a very good example of such a problem.

Comment: @dfhwze Sure, i'll do the post

Comment: The `Directory.Exists` call may be safely removed. From the docs on `CreateDirectory`, "Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path *unless they already exist*."

Comment: I didn't noticed that then I should look more attentively at the BCL doc, thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen with @t3chb0t and @dfhwze I have been misusing the TPL. I also don't see any point on `.ConfigureAwait(false)` a `Task.WhenAll()` call, also with the *async all-the-way* rule, using an awaitable task for this case would have me to convert many of my APIs to async one.

So they provided me these solutions :

- Modifiy my task creation logic this way :  `tasks.AddRange(filesPath.Select(async d2PFilePath => await Task.Run(() => UnpackD2PFile(d2PFilePath))));` and removing the `Task.Delay(10);` on my `UnpackD2PFile(string path)` task
- Use the `Parallel.Foreach()` loop to let the framework create and handle the concurrency and also allow me to keep a synchronous API

Both of these solutions completed the work in the same time, and provided this output :

[image: new application output]

As you can see now the behavior is quite different than before, not every task start at the same moment, also now there is a delay before every progress bars shown up. But we gained almost 2sec on the total execution time :)

**I highly recommend to use the Parallel approach as it is the easiest one to implement.**